# OMDB/TMDB next episode date

Tags: php, json, api

Is there any way to get air date of next TV series episode using OMDB/TMDB API?
For example, tomorrow should air episode 8 of the second season. I want to display tomorrows date today. I explored all documentation on both OMDB and TMDB websites, and couldn't find any solution.

Or maybe there is better API or way?

Answer (score 1):

Answer to my question is: http://www.tvmaze.com/api.
It has "nextepisode" option.